# How to finish compiling element, if directive sets terminal: true?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jIMyxlkvzHNIYrEmMAbY).

I'm trying to create a directive that re-arranges it's child elements. I can't use a simple `ng-transclude` because I want to put some child elements in different places within the template. I've learned that I need to set `terminal: true` and control compilation myself, but how do you do that?  As you can see in that code the `ng-if` and `ng-model` on the child elements have been compiled, but are not working properly.

One specific thing I may be doing wrong: the second argument to the `$compile` function. I don't know what it is, and the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile), says nothing but "function available to directives".

Here's the directive in question:

```
.directive('controlGroup', function ($compile, $log) {
   var template = "<div class='control-group'>" +
                  "<label class='control-label'></label>" +
                  "<div class='controls'></div>" +
                  "</div>";
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     terminal: true,
     priority: 100,
     compile: function (elt, attrs) {
       // Re-arrange element, inserting parts into template from above.
       var labelText = elt.find('label').text();
       var inputsAndMessages = elt.children().filter('input, button, select, .text-error');
       var newElt = $(template);
       newElt.find('.control-label').text(labelText);
       newElt.find('.controls').append(inputsAndMessages);
       elt.html('').append(newElt);

       // Now, how to finish compiling and linking it?  What to pass for 2nd arg?
       var link_ = $compile(elt, null, 99);  

       function link (scope, elt, attrs) {
       }
       return link;
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `var link_ = $compile(elt, null, 99);` returned a template function. [$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)  :

> Compiles a piece of HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a
>   template function, which can then be used to link scope and the
>   template together.

Now you just need to execute that template against a scope.  Since there's no scope at compile time, we need to do it in your link function, like so:

```
function link (scope, elt, attrs) {
   link_(scope);
}
```

That fixes it:  [Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZERILBy94Psgbb5koQj9?p=preview)

The second parameter is a transclusion function that would give you access to the cloned element and scope if you were transcluding.  Since you're not transcluding, null is fine to pass in.